# GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0 error

Tags: jackson-databind, spring-data-redis

I am getting below exception  using GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer.

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
> Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xa0  at [Source: [B@5fe2e364; line: 1,
> column: ---] (through reference chain: com.abc.def.FromRedis ["desc"])

Example Json for this is –

```
{
"@class":"com.abc.def.FromRedis",
"name":"abc",
"age":15,
"desc":"Some description that contain space and than word Class",
}
```

After some research it appears that one extra space before word Class in desc field is causing this error, any insights and steps to resolve will be appreciated.